# MVC Routing: How to map two names to one action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, multilingual

I'd like to have one route that gives the option of two urls but maps to one action. A good example would be for multilingual application. Lets take english and french for example.

This seems simple at first, technically you can do:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "the hi route english" ,
  "welcome/sayhi/{id}" ,
  new { controller = "Welcome" , action = "SayHi" , id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
  "the hi route french" ,
  "bienvenu/direallo/{id}" ,
  new { controller = "Welcome" , action = "SayHi" , id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

But that means that you'll have to define two routes for every action. Or a little better solution, create a custom Route class that takes more params to handle bilingualism.

If I go option 1 or 2, It means I have to define every single routes of the WelcomeController because I cannot use {action} in my route.

Ideally, i'd like to be able to define at least action name via metadata and then grab it via reflection or something.

i.e.:

```
[ActionName( { "fr", "direallo" }, {"en", "sayhi"})]
public ActionResult SayHi(string id){
     //check current thread culture...
}
```

I am not quite sure where to starts, any ideas? Tips?

Thank you,

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146227/how-to-route-a-multiple-language-url-with-a-mvc

Comment: its pretty good, but I'm wondering if there is some way to avoid building a dictionary outside the controller.

Comment: This is a configuration item in my opinion, and should be outside of the controller anyway. But that it just my two cents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options starting points here, roughly they are (in order of implementation complexity):

- A route per language (as you outlined above)
- [A regex route constraint](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs) e.g.

  ```
  routes.MapRoute(
      "the hi route",
      "{controllerName}/{actionName}/{id}",
      new { controller = "Welcome" , action = "SayHi" , id = UrlParameter.Optional },
      new { controllerName = @"welcome|bienvenu", actionName = @"sayhi|direallo" }
  );
  ```
- You could create a base controller, which is inherited by a subclass per language and define a language specific action name for each base controller action method
- You could create your own (or use the [one](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/01/26/Translating-routes-%28ASPNET-MVC-and-Webforms%29.aspx) provided in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146227/how-to-route-a-multiple-language-url-with-a-mvc) to the comment by Justin Pihony) custom routing constraint

Comment: If these are the only options, I guess last one remains the most elegant solution, and I already got it working :)

Comment: this gets tricky when you're domain defines the language you're in and then you have to add links depending on languages.