# Alternate names for querystring parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it somehow possible to set alternate names for querystring parameters in ASP.NET MVC?

I have this simple controller Index action:

```
public ActionResult Index(color = "")
{
    ...
}
```

Calling `http://mysite.com/mypage/?color=yellow` works quite nicely, the `color` parameter automatically picks up its value "yellow" from the querystring.

But now I would like to have a localized variant of the same page, with “pretty” localized parameters, but still working with the same controller method. Example: `http://mysite.com/mypage/?farve=gul`. Here I would like “gul” to be passed in as the `color` parameter to the default `Index()` ation method.

How do I set mappings for alternate names for querystring parameters?

Comment: Possible Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146227/how-to-route-a-multiple-language-url-with-a-mvc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do I set mappings for alternate names for querystring parameters?

You could write a custom model binder.

So as in every ASP.NET MVC application you start by writing a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

and then a model binder for this model:

```
public class MyViewModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var query = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
        var value = query["color"] ?? query["gul"] ?? query["couleur"];
        return new MyViewModel
        {
            Color = value,
        };
    }
}
```

which will be registered at your `Application_Start`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(MyViewModel), new MyViewModelBinder());
```

and now your controller action may take the view model as parameter:

```
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

Of course you could make the model binder more flexible by using some custom attribute on the property:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [PossibleQueries("color", "gul", "couleur")]
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

and in the model binder read those values and try reading them from the query string until you find one that is not null.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented a custom model binder - works perfectly. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about a second controller with a localized/pretty name where the actions and parameters have localized names and call the actions from the default/english controller? With this method you have all parts of the url localized.

```
Controller mypage
{
    ActionResult Index(string color)
    {
        // normal code
    }
}

Controller meineseite
{
    ActionResult Index(string farbe)
    {
        return mypage.Index(farbe);
    }
}
```