# Custom names for actions to appear on Url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to change the way our actionresult names appear on the URL.

I tried using `[ActionName()]` attribute on the actionresult declaration and modifying `routes.Maproute()` parameters in RouteConfig but it just caused application errors. Apparently, I'm missing something or doing it all wrong.

Simply, I'm trying to make the following actionresult appear as "giris" on url.

```
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl, string lang = "tr")
{
    code code code
}
```

and this is the part about this actionresult

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "LoginTr",
    "login",
    new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", lang = "tr" }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    "LoginEn",
    "en/login",
    new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", lang = "en" }
);
```

Also how can I make the custom url's work for different page languages?

Comment: Do you mean you want the urls to be `.../giris` and `.../en/giris` respectively?

Comment: actually /en URL's will remain to be in English so it should keep being /en/login. I don't know how to handle this since they map to same actionresult

Comment: Refer [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146227/how-to-route-a-multiple-language-url-with-a-mvc) for some options

Comment: My main problem of not making them appear with custom names still persists, different language is next part.

Comment: @EgeBayrak did you try to use Login(string returnUrl, string lang = "tr", string keyword = "giris") and [Route("/{lang}/{keyword}")]

Comment: If you want to translate URLs to multiple languages, you can use [RouteLocalization](https://github.com/Dresel/RouteLocalization) to do it (or reverse-engineer the bits you need). Keep in mind, URLs are just cosmetic just like every other part of the UI, so they can exist in resource files just like other content.